# What is nwjs which got installed as part of pgadmin4?

Tags: macos

I just finished installing pgadmin4 on my Mac from this url:

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v5.6/macos/

When I started the program I got a notification from nwjs, which looks weird.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

pgadmin4 consists of two parts: a python server and a desktop browser window that's called the Desktop Runtime Standalone Application. This desktop browser is built on NW.js (formerly node-webkit). Apparently, as part of the MacOS integration, NW.js drops a widget in the Notifications panel of the System preferences. You can customize its behavior there.

More info here:

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.1/desktop_deployment.html

https://nwjs.io/

Comment: Oops, pgadmin link appears to 404 :(